# SpringBoot JPA repository save method not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I will get List of JSONs from my MobileApp and I am converting those to a DataModel and then trying to insert the list of dataModel as a bulk.

This is my Data Model or Entity Object.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "cab_boarding")
public class CabBoardingModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "gpid")
    String gpid;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    Long latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    Long longitude;

    @Column(name = "vehicle_number")
    String vehicleNumber;

    @Column(name = "boarding_time")
    OffsetDateTime boardingTime;

}
```

This is my Repository Interface

```
public interface CBRepository extends CrudRepository<CabBoardingModel, Long> {

    List<CabBoardingModel> findAll();

    List<CabBoardingModel> save(List<CabBoardingModel> cabBoardingModels);

    Optional<CabBoardingModel> findById(Long id);

}
```

Below is the service tier that calls this `save` method

```
@Service
public class CBService {


    private CBRepository cbRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CBService(CBRepository cbRepository) {
        this.cbRepository = cbRepository;
    }


    public List<CabBoardingModel> create(List<CabBoardingModel> cabBoardingModelList) {
        List<CabBoardingModel> cbCreatedList = cbRepository.save(cabBoardingModelList);
        return cbCreatedList;
    }
}
```

Getting the below exception while accessing the save method

```
 2018-02-15 23:49:03.407 ERROR [smpoc-service-cabboarding,1b921dc7bf735306,1b921dc7bf735306,false] 2988 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] f.c.b.a.w.e.h.ControllerExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!
    at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.getPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:227) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:507) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'

Comment: Remove the additional methods in your repository, Spring Data already provides all of those. Work with the framework not around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `saveAll` method in Spring Data is only available with Spring Data 2.x (the link you provided links always to the documentation of the latest version). However, with Spring Boot 1.5, it uses an older Spring Data version, where the following documentation applies: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.13.10.RELEASE/api/

As you can see, here the method signature is

```
<S extends T> Iterable<S>   save(Iterable<S> entities)
```

Comment: I tried using save method. I get  `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!`

Comment: Please update your question with the changed code and specify, what exactly you did.

Comment: Can you add the code, where you actually call the save method?

Comment: You just have to remove your custom save method and use the one which is already part of the CrudRepository interface

Comment: Agree with @dunny,  use inbox repository interface instead of you custom implementation

Answer (score 0):

You should add @Transactional annotation to your method, so spring will handle the transaction and commit your changes.
This usually comes on the @Service class, but I see in your example that you do not have one, so put it on the controller (or add a service layer, I think it's better)